# How to find a Wikidata entity by property?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, linked-data, wikidata-api

I would like to know, is there a way to find a Wikidata entity by specified property using their API. For example, there are plenty entities that have Freebase ID property (Property:P646). It's unique identifier and I want to get an entity by this identifier.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**updated answer**: using the SPARQL endpoint]

wdq is being replaced by an official [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) endpoint, where this query looks like this:

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P646 "/m/0gnfq" .
}
```

you can [try it at query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20v%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP646%20%22%2Fm%2F0gnfq%22%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

and to get this query's results in JSON, you can make a request at "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=YOURQUERY" where YOURQUERY is the URI-encoded SPARQL query:

https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%20PREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP646%20%22%2Fm%2F0gnfq%22%20.%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%20%7D

[**old answer**: using WDQ]

you can fetch the wmflabs API ([documentation](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html)) like this:

```
http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=string[646:/m/0gnfq]
```

Here, I query the wikidata entities with Property `646` of value `/m/0gnfq`.

The answer will look like this:

```
{
  "status": {
    "error": "OK",
    "items": 1,
    "querytime": "161ms",
    "parsed_query": "STRING[646:'/m/0gnfq']"
  },
  "items": [
    180736
  ]
}
```

The entity I was looking for is thus `Q180736`.

Here, the query uses the `string` parameter as freebase IDs are strings in wikidata, but for properties implying wikidata entities as value type, you will need to use the `claim` parameter. An example from the documentation:

> claim[138:676555] returns all items that are named after
>   (P138) Francis of Assisi (Q676555).

Comment: Looks like there are no others options currently. It's kinda weird that so ambitious project doesn't have such simple functionality.

Comment: this September 2013 piece on the [wdq tool background story](http://magnusmanske.de/wordpress/?p=72) is very insightful on this issue: it's really not that simple apparently.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a SPARQL endpoint at https://query.wikidata.org

There you can type in your SPARQL query for Wikidata. e.g., for the Freebase property it could look like this:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX q: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?subject ?subjectLabel WHERE {
  ?subject wdt:P646 ?object .

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
} LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer [Wikidata Query API](https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html), but if you need some more information about the items you can use [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bbacklinks). For example, in your case, all items that link to [Freebase identifier (P646)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P646) property are:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&generator=backlinks&gblnamespace=0&gbllimit=5000&prop=info&gbltitle=Property:P646
```